# Which statistical test to use in R? Unbalanced design with one dependent variable and multiple independent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, unbalanced-classes, biostatistics, nested-data, univariate

it's been a while since I've had to do any statistics and I need a little help determining which statistical model/test to use in R. My background is more with multivariate stats, so it's been a while since I've done any univariate analyses.

I'm essentially looking at growth of 3 coral genotypes (same species) which were micro fragmented and placed on all available sides of bricks (5 sides). These bricks, which come in 3 different colors, were placed on an array (plastic square frame with mesh in the middle) and these arrays were repeated 4 times in 4 locations. Each array had 9 bricks on it, which allowed for 3 replicates of each genotype per array but on different colored bricks (so one replicate per color brick per array). This all in all gives be 180 data points (growth per day of a coral fragment). Growth per day was calculated by comparing imagej estimates of live tissue area from day 0 to day 250, so the difference in growth between the 2 time points was essentially just divided by 250.

This is a preliminary study (so not much data) to ascertain what might be driving coral growth (of a particular species) the most, is it genotype, color of substrate, orientation, or location, or any combination of these factors and with this data we can improve reef restoration practices. These data will be used to do further experiments to look further into which factors seem to influence coral growth the most.

So I have one dependent variable, which is growth per day (continuous), and four categorical/nominal independent variables: array (A,B,C or D) where the samples were placed, brick color (gray, white or pink), side (N,S,E,W and Top) where the samples were located on a brick, and genotype (1,2 or 3).

This seems like a nested design to me, but I don't think I can do an ANOVA as it's somewhat unbalanced (16 coral fragments died in the experiment). Should I be looking at GLMs, GAMs, LMs? I was also looking at mixed effects models like LMMs and GLMMs, as genotype would be a random factor, whilst the others would be fixed (I believe), but I think I'd need more data to use these models.

Apologies for any jargon misuse it's been a while since I've done any stats. I have tried to find out the answer independently through reading etc, I'm just getting to the point where I'm spinning in circles and not getting anywhere, so I felt I needed some expert input to point me in the right direction. I know the answer is probably very simple, which just makes this all the more galling that I haven't worked it out yet :/

Many thanks in advance for any help and I'm happy to provide more information if needed.